# Why does not the model see the second foreign key?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the next code:

```
$project = Project::findOrFail($projectId);
$experiments = $project->experiments;

dd($experiments->find($experimentId)->statistic);
```

Why does not `Statistic` model see `project_id` foreign key?

Only this code work:

```
$experiments->find($experimentId)->statistic()->where('project_id', $project->id)->first()
```

> Project <-> Experiment (Many to Many);
>   Experiment -> Statistic (One to One)

Comment: Can you include your model definitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try eager loading experiments and statistic

```
$project = Project::with('experiment.statistic')->findOrFail($projectId);
$experiments = $project->experiments;

dd($experiments->find($experimentId)->statistic);
```